# What is the best way to mine Monero on Macbook Pro?

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, miners, xmrig

I have started mining Monero using the MineXMR pool and an XMRig miner. I have done some calculations and found that, at my current rate of roughly 800H/s, it would take me four years to mine one coin. Am I missing something? Is there a way to optimise this without investing in specialised equipment CPUs etc? I would be grateful for any help on this.

Please note that I am using a MacbookPro with a 2.3GHz processor and 8GB memory. Preferably, I want to increase my mining rate solely with this hardware.

Comment: Can you share pc build that costs 1k for 14Kh/s

Comment: @AimBotQ use https://pcpartpicker.com/list/ and pick a 3900X plus fast RAM and cheap  everything else. Easy sub-1K PC for ~14kh/s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like your laptop won't be particularly good at rendering large amounts of video/audio, playing the latest video games or compiling large codebases, it's not going to be very good at mining. One can build a desktop PC for less than a $1000 that will mine at ~14kh/s - that's not a particularly "specialized" PC. Using a laptop for mining 24/7 is not the smartest move either as it will struggle to keep cool and shorten it's lifespan.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. So, I guess I'll need specialised equipment then.

Comment: Not really "specialized". A *desktop* PC with a recent *desktop* processor like the AMD Ryzen 3000 series.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the comments above: Hmm, I will argue that if I need to *buy* new hardware, it does require specialized equipment. Not only that, but I have to spend $1000 to *maybe* make $1 per day? Then, also lose some portion of that each time I make a transaction to use the coins. I'm new to crypto, but it seems like exchanges are using us miners' time and money, while they're the ones actually raking in the profits. That's not even taking into account all the energy being used. Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, but it seems like a waste of my time so far (only been doing it for a week). I was led to believe I could pool a bunch of smaller machines (even RPis) and make some sort of teenie profit, but it doesn't appear to work that way. I'm certainly finding blocks and "contributing" to Monero, but I'm barely finding shares in order to get a payout (and then get penalized for "uncles"), which is apparently based on "luck" (I don't believe in luck in software, btw ;)) and has to happen in some small 6 hour window (p2pool) or else I get *nothing* for the blocks I did find. Someone must be making money, but like other "mining" efforts throughout history, it doesn't seem to be the miners (but at least we do get some and don't have to break our backs all day :))

BTW, also, thank you @jtgrassie for proving the accepted answer. Very helpful/informative for me